# Using regular expressions with cp

Tags: regular-expression, cp

This is a simple question. I'm trying to copy all of the files in the current directory that start with `axis-2` and end with `.jar` into a target directory, `~/MyDirectory`.

My first attempt was

```
cp '^axis2.*jar$' ~/MyDirectory
```

... but when I try this, `cp` outputs a "No such file or directory" error message.  I'm not sure I can use regular expressions with `cp`. I also haven't used regular expressions in a while, and my syntax could be off.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The shell on Linux/UNIX systems uses [glob patterns](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13), not regular expressions.  So, if you want to match file names starting with `axis2` and ending with `.jar`, you could use:

```shell
cp axis2*.jar /destination/directory
```

Answer (score 16):

If you have GNU `find` and GNU `cp` available, you can use regular expressions as in the following command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-basic -regex '.*/axis2[^/]*jar$' \
       -exec cp -t ~/MyDirectory {} +
```

This can be handy if neither glob pattern nor bash extended glob pattern suite your needs.

Answer (score 3):

I really like the regex syntax of the `rename` perl script (by Robin Barker and Larry Wall), e.g.:

> `rename "s/OldFile/NewFile/" OldFile*`
>
> `OldFile.c` and `OldFile.h` are renamed to `NewFile.c` and `NewFile.h`, respectively

I simply wanted the exact same thing with a copy command:

`copy "s/OldFile/NewFile/" OldFile*`

So I duplicated that script and changed the rename statement to copy via `File::Copy`. Et voila! A copy command with perl-regex syntax: [jcward/copy](https://gist.github.com/jcward/0ead33bd79f2061c68728cc82582241f).

Answer (score 1):

To use regular expressions in shell globs, you could use the `ksh93` shell:

```
cp ~(E)^axis2.*jar$ ~/MyDirectory
```

(`E` for *extended* regexps. You can also use `G` for basic regexps, `P` for perl-like regexps, `A`/`X` for augmented regexps).

Or the `zsh` shell:

```
cp *(e['[[ $REPLY =~ "^axis2.*jar$" ]]']) ~/MyDirectory
```

That uses *extended* regexps unless you set the `rematchpcre` option in which case it uses perl-like regexps (as implemented by libpcre).

Answer (score 0):

There is a command `fd` (sometimes named `fdfind`) that is a simple, user-frendly version of `find`.

With `fd` we can:

```
fd regexp             ... to get files matching regexp
... -x command        ... to execute `command` on the files
```

So I suggest something along the lines of:

```
fd '^axis2.*jar$'  -x cp -t ~/MyDirectory
```